# Adding points to a mplfinance Plot

Tags: matplotlib, mplfinance

Is it possible to add points to a mpf plot? I know that you can add vlines and hlines but it doesn't seem to be easy to add single points to a plot.

Answer (score 1):

You can add points using `mpf.make_addplot(data,type='scatter')`

`data` will have to be the same length as your original data frame (passed into `mpf.plot()`) ... just fill data with `float('nan')` or `numpy.nan` values where you ***do not*** want points.

See [**this tutorial**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb) for more details.